# Group similar values in the array

Tags: php, ajax

Here is the array, which I have posted through Ajax and get into the ajax.php file. Now i want to add a new array, as shown below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 5000
            [invoice] => 476
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 5000
            [invoice] => 396
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 1490
            [invoice] => 1083
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 1490
            [invoice] => 498


  )
)
```

I also want to add this if contact id are same, then invoice will be added

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 5000
            [invoice] => Array (
                    [0] =>476,
                    [1] =>396
            )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 1490
            [invoice] => Array (
                    [0] =>1083,
                    [1] =>498
            )
        )
)
```

I tried to do it, without success. Here is my code:

```
$invtemp =array();
 foreach($_POST['invoice_id'] as $value){
    if(!in_array($value['contact_id'], $invtemp, true)){
         $arr = array($value['contact_id'] => $value['invoice'] );
         array_push($invtemp, $arr);    
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I have no error just want to add array like above, but there is error in checking code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve with simple `foreach`:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $arr[$value['contact_id']]['contact_id'] = $value['contact_id'];
    $arr[$value['contact_id']]['invoice'][] = $value['invoice'];
}

print_r($arr);
```

This provides:

```
Array
(
    [5000] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 5000
            [invoice] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 476
                    [1] => 396
                )

        )

    [1490] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => 1490
            [invoice] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1083
                    [1] => 498
                )

        )

)
```

To reset the keys:

```
print_r(array_values($arr));
```

---

*Not so important*, but to make it cleaner, you can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    extract($value);
    $arr[$contact_id]['contact_id'] = $contact_id;
    $arr[$contact_id]['invoice'][] = $invoice;
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Yes you can, reset the keys by using: `array_values($arr);`

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple.

```
$invtemp = array();
foreach($_POST['invoice_id'] as $value){
    $invtemp[$value['contact_id']]['invoice'][] = $value['invoice'];
}
```

By indexing your array by contact_id, you ensures yourself that there is only one subarray for each contact_id.

By adding each new invoice as a new index, you ensure yourself that each invoice is added to your final array even there are already invoices associted with the contact_id.

And since your keys are the contact_ids, you don't need to store them as values to have them available.

Comment: your code has error please check than post the answer.

Comment: @AnandPandey Could you be more explicit...?

Comment: Error in this line:  $invtemp[$value['contact_id']]['invoice'][] = $value['invoice'];

Comment: There is virtually only one line in that piece of code, so I could expect potential errors to probably come from it. What error did you notice ? I see no errors and it works as planned when tested. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: @AnandPandey So what you call an error is actually a difference with the array format of your expected solution...?

Comment: In that case my code is wrong to as it doesn't give the same output as you want. I believe OPs array is inefficient.

Comment: @Andreas That's not really the point. In fact, maybe he needs to pass it to a function that extract both information from the same array level. On the other hand, he could have stated that in the first comment, instead of enigmatically pointing it as an error without saying what it was.

Comment: @ksjohn I understand that. But in my opinion an array with two sets of values shouldn't have to be as large as OP has written. I would personally rewrite the other code to fit a smaller array. Any time you add layers to an array it makes it more complex and (most of the times) harder to use. Of course it depends on how much rewriting needs to be done.

Comment: @Andreas I fully agree.

Answer (score 0):

This will create an array similar to what you want but with the key as contact_id.
It creates a slightly more compact array that will still be easy to use.

```
$arr = array
(
Array
    (
        "contact_id" => 5000,
        'invoice' => 476
    ),

Array
    (
        'contact_id' => 5000,
        'invoice' => 396
    ),

Array
    (
        'contact_id' => 1490,
        'invoice' => 1083
    ),

Array
    (
        'contact_id' => 1490,
        'invoice' => 498


));

$res =array();
Foreach($arr as $subarr){
    Foreach($subarr as $key => $val){
       If($key == "contact_id") {
          If(!isset($res[$val])) $res[$val] = array();
          $cid = $val;
       }Else{
          $res[$cid][]= $val;
       }
    }
}

Var_dump($res);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
 [5000]=>
array(2) {
    [0]=> int(476)
    [1]=> int(396)
  }
[1490]=> 
array(2) {
    [0]=> int(1083)
    [1]=> int(498)
  }
}
```

See here: https://3v4l.org/cmH8P

Comment: You are also correct but array_values() reset the keys.

Comment: @Anand yes??? And what does that have to do with it? I have not written anything that you should use it. `unset($res)` will remove the array. But that to irrelevant for the code above.